# anchorText not allowed in markerCluster

Tags: google-maps-api-3

So I'm using a custom icon for my clusters, and this causes the text to be off center.  No problem, right?  just use the anchorText?  Well, there are problems.

```
  let anchor: Array<number> = [9,3];
  let styles = [{
    url: "../../assets/img/mapIcons/clusterDot.svg",
          width: 50,
          height:50,
          textSize:25,
          textColor:"white",
          anchorText: anchor,
    }];

this.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.markers, mcOptions);
```

So the problem is, if I use the new naming of 'AnchorText', I will get the following error (however, it will properly center my text)

```
Argument of type '{ maxZoom: number; styles: { url: string; width: number; height: number; textSize: number; textColor: string; anchorText: number[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MarkerClustererOptions'.
  Types of property 'styles' are incompatible.
    Type '{ url: string; width: number; height: number; textSize: number; textColor: string; anchorText: number[]; }[]' is not assignable to type
```

This error won't stop angular for displaying it properly (but I can't check in an error as it won't pass the build test)

Now, if I change it to 'anchor' (apparently the old name of the object) it will remove the error, but it won't actually center the text.

I'm using the latest version: "@googlemaps/markerclustererplus": "^1.0.3"

What is the proper way I should be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So even though nobody shows using this in all the examples online, I did find this in the bitBucket.  .WithDefaultStyles allows you to properly set the anchorText.

```
      let styles = [
    MarkerClusterer.withDefaultStyle({
          url: "../../assets/img/mapIcons/clusterDot.svg",
          width: 56,
          height:56,
          textSize:25,
          textColor:"white",
          anchorText: [-4, 0]
    })]


  let mcOptions = {
    maxZoom:21,
    styles:styles
};

this.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: Hi Limey, you should have to define the type of styles here to avoid the error of anchorText which you are facing. like 
let styles : ClusterIconStyle[] = [
    MarkerClusterer.withDefaultStyle({
          url: "../../assets/img/mapIcons/clusterDot.svg",
          width: 56,
          height:56,
          textSize:25,
          textColor:"white",
          anchorText: [-4, 0]
    })]
then it would allow you to use anchorText with no error. I was also facing this error even anchorText was working fine, but angular was not allowing me to create build, after defining type it works.